# Issue while converting xml to json, and then back to xml

Tags: node.js, xml, data-conversion

I'm facing an issue when converting XML to JSON and then JSON to XML.
I'm using this [xml-js](https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js/) npm library.

**data.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property name="DESCRIPTION" value="Group 1 &amp; , &quot; , &lt;"/>
```

**test.js**

```js
const convert = require('xml-js');
const fs = require('fs');

const xml = fs.readFileSync('data.xml',).toString();

const result = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: false, spaces: 2});

const output = convert.json2xml(result,{compact: false, spaces: 2});

fs.writeFileSync('output.xml', output);
```

**output.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property name="DESCRIPTION" value="Group 1 & , &quot; , <"/>
```

I was expecting to get the below result in output.xml

**expected output.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<property name="DESCRIPTION" value="Group 1 &amp; , &quot; , &lt;"/>
```

Any idea why I'm getting that data on converting from JSON to XML.

Comment: maybe because of bugs in the json2xml() implementation? https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js/issues/26

Comment: Yes looks like an issue with the xml-js library itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the problem fixed by using attributeValueFn.

```js
const convert = require('xml-js');
const fs = require('fs');

const xml = fs.readFileSync('data.xml',).toString();

const result = convert.xml2json(xml, {compact: false, spaces: 2,
                 attributeValueFn: function(value) {
                     return value.replace(/&/g,'AMPERSAND_CHARACTER');
                                    }
               });

console.log('JSON : ' + result);                               

const output = convert.json2xml(result,{compact: false, spaces: 2,
                  attributeValueFn: function(value) {
                 return value.replace(/AMPERSAND_CHARACTER/g, '&amp;')
                        .replace(/</g, '&lt;');
                                    }
               });

fs.writeFileSync('output.xml', output);
```

Comment: Hi, I try to use your code but it tells me error:
Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
Error: Can't resolve 'xml-js' do you know how I can fix it? thank u...

Comment: `npm install xml-js`